# Manifest icons in custom Azure DevOps extension hubs and hub groups

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I am developing an Azure DevOps extension. Experimenting with the DevOps [UI extension sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/tree/master/ui) raises a question for me. I enabled the Preview features in Azure DevOps having a more fancy UI. Azure default hubs and hub groups like Tests, Repos and so on do have a nice coloured icons in the menu bar. Whereas my custom Sample UI do not. They are just grey. And it looks like I cannot manifest icons for my custom hubs and hub groups. Anybody here who knows more about this issue?

[image: The preview features in Azure DevOps and my Sample UI]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/web-navigation?view=vsts#hub-icon) will most likley solve your problem

Make sure your vss.extension.json file follow this pattern:

```
{
   "id": "my-extension",
   "publisherId": "my-publisher",
   ...
   "contributions": [
     {
        "id": "example-hub",
        "type": "ms.vss-web.hub",
        "targets": [
            "ms.vss-code-web.code-hub-group"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "name": "My Hub",
            "iconAsset": "my-publisher.my-extension/images/fabrikam-logo.png",
            "_sharedData": {
                "assets": [
                    "my-publisher.my-extension/images/fabrikam-logo.png"
                ]
            }
        }
   }
 ],
 "files": [
    {
       "path": "images/fabrikam-logo.png",
       "addressable": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer. I want to highlight the value of the iconAsset property. It must by filled with the path pattern of the icon {publisher-id}.{extension-id}/{asset-path} for example MyPublisher.MyextensionId.MyExtensionContributionsId/MyLogo.png