# How to use font or CSS as icon for hub in Azure DevOps Extension?

Tags: azure-devops-extensions

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53582701/manifest-icons-in-custom-azure-devops-extension-hubs-and-hub-groups) post I see that we can use images as icon for Azure DevOps hub. But I need to use icon from CSS or font.
Also, I see that icons in hubs (for example Pipelines) uses fabric-icons:

[image: fabric icons]

How to use font or CSS as icon for hub in Azure DevOps Extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/8440) post which says that we can use the `iconName` property with fabric-icons names from [here](https://uifabricicons.azurewebsites.net/).

My sample config:

[image: my config sample]

On a DevOps site, it looks like this:

[image]